# How do I render a map activity on android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm very, very new to Android and am currently trying to develop an app dealing with location. I want to start off on a map activity but after the first few times of rendering it correctly, it started giving me unrendered frangments and a rendering error. Pls Help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use the MapActivity provided by google in android studios.

Also make sure you have entered correct API key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this default activity on Android Studio.

[image]

Then, make sure you have an API key from google. Here's the link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

After that:

[image]

**Note: Always make sure that you are connected to the internet for the maps to render. Hope this helps!**